# I am not getting the concept actually of dimension of intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$$W_1=\{(0,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)|\forall x_i\in \Bbb R, i=2,3,4,5 \} $$
$$W_2=\{(x_1,0,x_3,x_4,x_5)|\forall x_i \in \Bbb R, i=1,3,4,5\}$$

be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^5$ then what is $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$?

Comment: The symbol $\forall$ is incorrectly used in these expressions, and should be removed. These are generating clauses in set-builder notation; there is no predicate to apply "for all" to.

Answer (score 3):

$W_1$ consists of all vectors whose first component is zero, and $W_2$ consists of all vectors whose second component is zero.

1) Can you describe the elements of $W_1 \cap W_2$?

2) Can you find a basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$? The size of any basis will be the dimension of $W_1 \cap W_2$.

Comment: when i attempted the basis i got was (0,0,x3,x4,x5) and hence dimension would be 3 but answer states 2?

Comment: @manish The vectors $(0,0,1,0,0)$, $(0,0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,0,1)$ are obviously in $W_1\cap W_2$, and linearly independant, how could the dimension be $2$?

Comment: Dimension should be 3 right ?

Comment: thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut , i too got 3 .I guess there might be mistake in answer

Answer (score 0):

What you can say that $W_1$ is generated by 
$\{   $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
   \end {pmatrix} $$ \} $.

& $W_2$ is generated by 
$\{   $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
   \end {pmatrix} $$ \} $.

So $W_1 \cap W_2=Sp \{ $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
       0\\
   \end {pmatrix}  $$, $$ \begin{pmatrix}
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       0\\
       1\\
   \end {pmatrix} $$ \} $. 
So dimention is $3$.